# How to apply SVD on TF-IDF Dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, tf-idf, svd

I have applied the pyspark tf-idf functions and get back the following results.

```
| features |
|----------|
| (35,[7,9,11,12,19,26,33],[1.2039728043259361,1.2039728043259361,1.2039728043259361,1.6094379124341003,1.6094379124341003,1.6094379124341003,1.6094379124341003])  |
| (35,[0,2,4,5,6,11,22],[0.9162907318741551,0.9162907318741551,1.2039728043259361,1.2039728043259361,1.2039728043259361,1.2039728043259361,1.6094379124341003]) |
```

So a dataframe having 1 column (features) which contains SparseVectors as rows.

Now i want to build the IndexRowMatrix from this dataframe so that i can run the svd function which is described over here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=svd#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRowMatrix.computeSVD

I have tried the following but didn't work:

```
mat = RowMatrix(tfidfData.rdd.map(lambda x: x.features))

TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector'> into Vector
```

I used RowMatrix because to construct it i don't have to provide tuple but i can't even build RowMatrix. IndexedRowMatrix will be more difficult for me.

So how to run the IndexedRowMatrix on the out put of tf-idf dataframe in pyspark ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to solve it.
So as error suggested that RowMatrix won't accept `pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector` vector, So I converted this vector into `pyspark.mllib.linalg` Pay attention to `ml` and `mllib`. Now the following is the code snippet which will convert TF-IDF output to RowMatrix and you apply computeSVD method on it.

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
mat = RowMatrix(df.rdd.map(lambda v: Vectors.dense(v.rawFeatures.toArray()) ))
```

I have converted to Dense matrix but you can write some extra lines of code to convert `ml.linalg.SparseVector` into `mllib.linalg.SparseVector`

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse for not commenting in the original answer, I don't have requisite reputation points yet. To speed up things it would be beneficial to create a `mllib.linalg.SparseVector`. Its really straightforward if the following modification is made:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
mat = RowMatrix(df.rdd.map(lambda v: Vectors.fromML(v.rawFeatures)))
```